# non-abelian Galois cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $1 \to A \to B \to C \to 1$ be a short exact sequence of (not necessarily abelian) $G$-modules. Passing to non-abelian cohomology, we have the exact sequence of pointed sets
$$ 1 \to A^G \to B^G \to C^G \to H^1(G,A) \to H^1(G,B) \to H^1(G,C)$$
My question is

> Is there a way to extend this exact sequence a bit further, i.e. up to $H^2$?

I know there is some work that defines $H^2$ in a sensible way, but I'm not whether the above exact sequence can be extended.

Comment: There is an entire book on this topic called Cohomologie Non-Abeline by Giraud.

Comment: In [_Cohomologie non-abélienne_, Ch. III §4], Giraud describes an extended exact sequence of the desired form for short exact sequences satisfying a special condition. But I do not know any of the details.

Comment: @ZhenLin The resulting sequence sends a torsor to the trivial gerbe coming from the exact sequence.